# Building a sparse array from given lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

Given some lists

```
lstRow1 = {{"C1", "C2", "C3"}, {1, 2, 3}};
lstRow2 = {{"C2", "D1", "D2"}, {4, 5, 6}};
lstRow3 = {{"C1", "D2", "D3"}, {7, 8, 9}};
lstRow4 = {{}, {}};
lstRow5 = {{"D1", "D2", "E1"}, {10, 11, 12}};
lstRow6 = {{}, {}};

lstHead = {{"C1", "H1"}, {"C2", "H1"}, {"C3", "H1"}, {"D1", 
    "H2"}, {"D2", "H2"}, {"D3", "H2"}, {"E1", "H3"}};
```

how to build a sparse arrary like this:

```
lstSparse = {
   {"H1", "0", "0", "H2", "0", "0", "H3"},
   {"C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2", "D3", "E1"}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 0, 12}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

or **ZERO**s could be replaced by blank string, to be like this.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \text{H1} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{H2} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{H3} \\
 \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1} \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 & 12 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\to
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 \text{H1} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{H2} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{H3} \\
 \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1} \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{} & 4 & \text{} & 5 & 6 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 7 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 8 & 9 & \text{} \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 10 & 11 & \text{} & 12 \\
 \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = {lstRow1, lstRow2, lstRow3, lstRow4, lstRow5, lstRow6};
ac = ArrayComponents[rows[[All, 1]]];
sa = SparseArray[Join @@ (Thread /@ Thread[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, ac, {2}] -> 
        rows[[All, 2]]]), {Length@rows, Max@ac}];

sa // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
>  7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 & 12 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, use `""` as the background element

```
sa2 = SparseArray[Join @@ (Thread /@ Thread[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, ac, {2}] -> 
            rows[[All, 2]]]), {Length@rows, Max@ac}, ""];
sa2 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  \text{} & 4 & \text{} & 5 & 6 & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  7 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 8 & 9 & \text{} \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 10 & 11 & \text{} & 12 \\
>  \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
headers = Join @@@ Transpose[PadRight /@ MapIndexed[{{"H" <> ToString[#2[[1]]]}, #} &, 
     GatherBy[DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ rows[[All, 1]]], StringTake[#, 1] &]]]
```

> {{0, "H1", 0, 0, "H2", 0, 0, "H3"}, {0, "C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2", 
>     "D3", "E1"}}

```
Join[headers, sa] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  \text{H1} & 0 & 0 & \text{H2} & 0 & 0 & \text{H3} \\
>  \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1} \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 4 & 0 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
>  7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 0 & 12 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Update:** Obtaining header rows from `lstHead`:

```
headers2 = {SequenceReplace[#[[1]], {b : (a_String) ..} :> 
     Sequence[a, ## & @@ ConstantArray[0, Length[{b}] - 1]]], #[[2]]} &@
  Reverse[Transpose[lstHead]]
```

> {{"H1", 0, 0, "H2", 0, 0, "H3"}, {"C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2", "D3", 
>     "E1"}}

Comment: Thanks! could the values `H1`\`H2`\`H3` in the head be picked from the original values in `lstHead` other than generated by codes?

Comment: @Jerry, thank you for the accept. I will post an update re pulling the first row headers from input data.