# Building a sparse array from given lists the 2nd case

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

Similar to [the 1st case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186827/building-a-sparse-array-from-given-lists), now given a list

```
lst = {{"row1", "H1", "C1", 1},
       {"row1", "H1", "C2", 2}, 
       {"row1", "H1", "C3", 3}, 
       {"row2", "H2", "D1", 2}, 
       {"row2", "H2", "D2", 3}, 
       {"row2", "H2", "D3", 4}, 
       {"row3", "H1", "C2", 8}, 
       {"row3", "H2", "D2", 9}, 
       {"row3", "H2", "D3", 10}, 
       {"row4", "", "", ""},
       {"row5", "H2", "D2", 10}, 
       {"row5", "H2", "D3", 11}, 
       {"row5", "H3", "E1", 12},
       {"row6", "", "", ""}};
```

I want to get a sparse array like this:

```
lstSparse = {{"0", "H1", "0", "0", "H2", "0", "0", "H3"}, 
            {"0", "C1", "C2", "C3", "D1", "D2", "D3", "E1"}, 
            {"row1", 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {"row2", 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0}, 
            {"row3", 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 10, 0}, 
            {"row4", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {"row5", 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 12},
            {"row6", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

or ZEROs could be replaced by blank string too, to be like this.

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \text{0} & \text{H1} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{H2} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{H3} \\
 \text{0} & \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1}
   \\
 \text{row1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
 \text{row3} & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 0 \\
 \text{row4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 \text{row6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$$$
\to
$$$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \text{} & \text{H1} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{H2} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{H3} \\
 \text{} & \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1}
   \\
 \text{row1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{row2} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 2 & 3 & 4 & \text{} \\
 \text{row3} & \text{} & 8 & \text{} & \text{} & 9 & 10 & \text{} \\
 \text{row4} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 \text{row5} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 \text{row6} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
\end{array}\right)$$

**Update:** a more complicated test data could be found here:

```
URLDownload["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztb03.png", "C:\\test.zip"];
ExtractArchive["C:\\test.zip", "C:\\"];

lstData = FromCharacterCode[BinaryReadList["C:\\test.txt"]];
lst = (StringSplit[StringReplace[#, {"{" -> "", "}" -> ""}], ","] & /@
     StringSplit[lstData, "\r\n"]);
```

[image: test data behind picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{spa, headers, 
      rc = Select[FreeQ[""]]@SortBy[#[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]], {#[[3]] &, First}], 
      rows = DeleteDuplicates[#[[All, 1]]], nr, nc, cIndex, rIndex},
    {nr, nc} = Length /@ {rows, DeleteDuplicates@rc[[All, 3]]};
    cIndex = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, DeleteDuplicates@rc[[All, 3]]];
    rIndex = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, rows];
    spa = SparseArray[Thread[rc[[All, {1, 3}]]->rc[[All, 4]] /. rIndex /. cIndex], 
      {nr, nc}];
    headers = PadLeft[#, 1 + Length@#] & /@ 
      {SequenceReplace[#[[1]], {b : (a_String) ..} :>
        Sequence[a, ## & @@ ConstantArray[0, Length[{b}] - 1]]], #[[2]]} &[
          Transpose[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Last]@rc[[All, {2, 3}]]]];
    Join[headers, Join[List /@ rows, spa, 2]]] &;

TeXForm @ f @ lst
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & \text{H1} & 0 & 0 & \text{H2} & 0 & 0 & \text{H3} \\
>  0 & \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1} \\
>  \text{row1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
>  \text{row3} & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 0 \\
>  \text{row4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
>  \text{row6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
lst2 = Join[lst, {{"row7", "", "", ""}, {"row8", "H1", "C4", 10}, {"row9", 
     "H2", "C5", 20}, {"row10", "H3", "E2", 30}}];
TeXForm @ f @ lst2
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & \text{H1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{H2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{H3} & 0 \\
>  0 & \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C3} & \text{C4} & \text{C5} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1} & \text{E2} \\
>  \text{row1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row3} & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 0 \\
>  \text{row6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row7} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row8} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row9} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{row10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thanks！Also I hope `H1``H2``H3`  use the original values not `H` with index insted.

Comment: Perfect codes help me lean sparse arrays!

Comment: I made a test appending `{"row8", "H1", "C4", 10}, {"row9", "H2", "C5", 20}, {"row10", "H3", "E2", 30}`  to `lst`, but the result does not appear as I wanted

Comment: `Index number` after `row\C-D-E-\H` might be not existing, so `Sort` might be applied before formating lists.

Comment: @Jerry, you are right about the need to sort if the input list is not in the right order. I will post an update with a fix.

Comment: I'm trying get it following your codes' steps, but I even cannot understand why `"" -> Sequence[]`  being used. :(

Comment: @Jerry, please see the updated version.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It works precisly on the current demo case, but I have applied it on a more complicated test case, probably there still be something to be fixed, I'll try send you the testdata via picture.

Comment: I have updated the question by uploading a complicated data for testing.

Comment: The part  `SortBy[#[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]], {#[[2]], #[[3]], First} &]` fixed and now becomes ok! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kglr, I could developed `fMakeSparseList` based on `Dataset` operation.

```
fMakeSparseList[ds_, {indexColName_?StringQ, classColName_?StringQ, 
   headColName_?StringQ, valueColName_?StringQ}] :=
    Module[ {dsCols, rc, rows, rowc, rowh, cols, nr, nc, cIndex, rIndex, 
      spa, ch, ch2, headers, result},

        dsCols = Normal@Keys@First@ds;
        rc = Select[FreeQ[""]]@
          ds[SortBy[
            ToExpression[
             "{#" <> classColName <> ",#" <> headColName <> ",# " <> 
              indexColName <> "}&"]]];
        rows = DeleteDuplicates@ds[All, indexColName];
        rowc = Complement[dsCols, {classColName, headColName, valueColName}];
        rowh = Values@DeleteDuplicates@ds[All, rowc];
        cols = DeleteDuplicates@rc[All, headColName];
        {nr, nc} = Length /@ {rows, cols};
        
        (*building sparse array*)
        cIndex = Normal@MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, cols];
        rIndex = Normal@MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, rows];
        spa = SparseArray[
          Thread[Values@Normal@rc[All, {indexColName, headColName}] -> 
              Normal@rc[All, valueColName]] /. rIndex /. cIndex, {nr, nc}];
        
        (*Headers*)
        ch = Transpose[
          DeleteDuplicatesBy[Last]@
           Values@Normal@rc[[All, {classColName, headColName}]]];
        ch2 = {SequenceReplace[#[[1]], {b : (a_String) ..} :> 
              Sequence[a, ## & @@ ConstantArray[0, Length[{b}] - 1]]], #[[
             2]]} &@ch;
        headers = PadLeft[#, Length@rowc + Length@#] & /@ ch2;
        result = Join[headers, Join[Flatten /@ List /@ rowh, spa, 2]];
        
        (*return*)
        Return[result];
    ]
```

before use `fMakeSparseList`, the list should be converted to `dataset`,

```
fGetDatasetFromList[list_?ListQ,cols_?ListQ] :=
    Module[ {ds,cols2,i},
        (*headers*)
        cols2 = If[ Length[cols]<=0,
                    Table["Col"<>ToString[i],{i,1,Length[Transpose@list]}],
                    cols
                ];
        ds = Dataset[list][All,AssociationThread[cols2,Range[Length[cols2]]]];
        (*return*)
        Return[ds];
    ]
fGetDatasetFromList[list_?ListQ] := fGetDatasetFromList[list,{}]
```

Now a new demo source list is listed as

```
lst = {{"row1", "", "H1", "C1", 1}, 
       {"row1", "", "H1", "C2", 2}, 
       {"row1", "", "H1", "C3", 3}, 
       {"row2", "id", "H2", "D1", 2}, 
       {"row2", "id", "H2", "D2", 3}, 
       {"row2", "id", "H2", "D3", 4}, 
       {"row3", "id", "H1", "C2", 8}, 
       {"row3", "id", "H2", "D2", 9}, 
       {"row3", "id", "H2", "D3", 10}, 
       {"row4", "id", "", "", ""}, 
       {"row5", "id", "H2", "D2", 10}, 
       {"row5", "id", "H2", "D3", 11}, 
       {"row5", "id", "H3", "E1", 12}, 
       {"row6", "id", "", "", ""}, 
       {"row7", "id", "H1", "C1", 9}, 
       {"row8", "id", "H1", "C4", 10}, 
       {"row9", "id", "H2", "C5", 20}, 
       {"row10", "id", "H3", "E2", 30},
       {"row11", "", "H3", "E2", 31}};

 ds = fGetDatasetFromList[lst];
```

[image]

then apply `fMakeSparseList` on `ds` and `columns` to get the result.

```
fMakeSparseList[ds, {"Col1", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"}] // TableForm//TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & \text{H1} & 0 & 0 & \text{H2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{H3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \text{C1} & \text{C2} & \text{C4} & \text{C5} & \text{D1} & \text{D2} & \text{D3} & \text{E1} & \text{E2} \\
 \text{row1} & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row2} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row3} & \text{id} & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row4} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row5} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 0 \\
 \text{row6} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row7} & \text{id} & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row8} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row9} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \text{row10} & \text{id} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 30 \\
 \text{row11} & \text{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 31 \\
\end{array}\right)$$